# Aliasing for tsconfig.app.json not working Angular 11

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I'm having an issue getting aliasing to work since I've moved my app into an angular project

None of my imports work with my "@app" alias

```
mainApp
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.json
│   angular.json    
│
└───projects
    │  
    └───my-project (That I need the aliasing for)
        │  tsconfig.app.json
        │ 
        └───src
             │  
             └───app
```

When I use:

```
import { MyService } from '@app/shared/services/my.service';
```

I get errors

In my tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I've tried

```
"@app/*": ["projects/my-project/src/app/*"],
```

I also updated my main tsconfig.json:

```
....
"baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
    "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
    "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
  },
...
```

And then serve the project:

```
ng serve --project my-project
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `tsconfig.json` in `my-project`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried copying the main tsconfig to my-project, but that still doesn't work, and from what I've seen doesn't the tsconfig.app extend the main tsconfig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was because my paths object was outside of the `compilerOptions` object, so:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["projects/my-/src/app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
```

worked!!!
Rather than

```
 "compilerOptions": {
.......
},"paths": {
      "@app/*": ["projects/my-project/src/app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    }
```

Comment: The entire Internet seems to guide you towards the latter, though your solution oddly enough also worked for me. Good job! I hope this can be found by others whom use Angular 12+.